# How can we solve this ODE

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Doing an physics exercise, I arrived at: $\frac{d(\frac{dx}{dy})}{dy}=\frac{1}{x^2}$

At first, I thought about something like $y = -ln(x)$, but was unable to prove it. So I was unable to use math definitions to arrive at this, like double integrating.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Multiplying both sides by $\frac{dx}{dy}$ gives
$$ \frac{dx}{dy}\frac{d(\frac{dx}{dy})}{dy}=\frac{1}{x^2}\frac{dx}{dy} $$
and hence
$$ \frac12\frac{d}{dy}\bigg(\frac{dx}{dy}\bigg)^2=-\frac{d}{dy}\bigg(\frac1{x}\bigg). $$
So
$$ \bigg(\frac{dx}{dy}\bigg)^2=-\frac2{x}+C_1. $$
Taking square root gives
$$ \frac{dx}{dy}=\pm\sqrt{-\frac2{x}+C_1}. $$
so
$$ \frac{dx}{\sqrt{-\frac2{x}+C_1}}=\pm dy. $$
Now integrating both sides will give
$$ y=\pm\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{-\frac2{x}+C_1}}+C_2 $$
which is easy to solve. I omit the detail.